# What is python actually doing when it searches my lists in this function?

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote the following. My goal was to try and create a robust way for the code to read sentences for a text-adventure game. I made lists (`h_answer1 and 2`) populated with the keywords I wanted the game to recognize, and then I asked for user input in the `mansr` function (`mansr` takes its argument and makes it lower case), and then I split that input into a list called `split_ans`.

This works about half the time. But if I input certain phrases, like "I believe I will search," it throws me through the else statement, even though "search" appears in my sentence.

If I understand correctly, the for-loop is setting `check` equal to each string in the `split_ans` list, and then the if-statement is checking to see if that particular `check` matches anything in the `h_answer` lists. So why would python go to the else statement when the if condition has been met?

```
def some_function():
   print "some stuff"
   ans = mansr(raw_input())
   split_ans = ans.split(' ')

   h_answer1 = ['walk', 'run', 'go']
   h_answer2 = ['search', 'look']

      for check in split_ans:
         if check in h_answer1:
            print "Some stuff"
            break
         elif check in h_answer2:
            print "Some stuff"
            ans = mansr(raw_input(' '))
            split_ans = ans.split(' ')
              <section omitted, it's a nested for-loop>
         else:
             print "I don't understand that input."
             some_function()
```

The traceback doesn't reveal much (`some_function` was named `long_hallway`, edited above in order to be more generic):

```
  File "test06.py", line 171, in <module> start()
  File "test06.py", line 92, in start long_hallway()
  File "test06.py", line 59, in long_hallway long_hallway()
  File "test06.py", line 59, in long_hallway long_hallway()
  File "test06.py", line 13, in long_hallway
  ans = mansr(raw_input('\n>>> '))
```

Answer (score 0):

That traceback is pretty unininformative. What was the associated exception?

One obvious source of possible problems is that you're re-using the ans and split_ans variables.  Since you are iterating on split_ans you may run into issues because you're trying to change it in mid execution, [which is a no-no.](http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/)

The other thing is - are you sure you want a break rather than a continue?  Do you want to escape the parsing loop after the first hit?